# Mysql union all select issue

Tags: mysql, union-all

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong here. I am joining multiple select statements from the same table using different Where statements with one of the selects being a join as well. I am attempting to use union all but I seem to be missing something and I cant figure out what it is. Any  help would be great. Below is my code:

```
SET @LASTQTR:=IF((QUARTER(CURDATE( ))-1) = 0, 4, QUARTER(CURDATE( ))-1);
SET @YR:=IF(@LASTQTR = 4, YEAR(NOW( ))-1, YEAR(NOW( )));

(SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS total, CONCAT(m1.first_name,' ', m1.last_name) AS fromName  FROM Referrals AS r JOIN Members AS m1 ON m1.id=r.from_id WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR  GROUP BY r.from_id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS external FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=1 GROUP BY from_id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS internal FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=2  GROUP BY from_id)
    ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The end result I am looking for from this query is to use the results in a while loop like so:

```
while ( $re = $q8->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo'<tr>
    <td style="width:40%;">'.$re['fromName'].'</td>
    <td class="text-right">'.$re['external'].'</td>
    <td class="text-right">'.$re['internal'].'</td>
    <td class="text-right">'.$re['total'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For union all the sets should have same not of columns. In your case first query has fromName too. Either remove that or put placeholders in other queries as well

```
SET @LASTQTR:=IF((QUARTER(CURDATE( ))-1) = 0, 4, QUARTER(CURDATE( ))-1);
SET @YR:=IF(@LASTQTR = 4, YEAR(NOW( ))-1, YEAR(NOW( )));

(SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS total, CONCAT(m1.first_name,' ', m1.last_name) AS fromName  FROM Referrals AS r JOIN Members AS m1 ON m1.id=r.from_id WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR  GROUP BY r.from_id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS external,'' FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=1 GROUP BY from_id)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT COUNT(id) AS internal,'' FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=2  GROUP BY from_id)
    ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10;
```

---

As per your comment (havent executed this)

```
(SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS total, CONCAT(m1.first_name,' ', m1.last_name) AS fromName,
(SELECT COUNT(id)  FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=1 GROUP BY from_id) AS external,
(SELECT COUNT(id)  FROM Referrals WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR AND rtype=2  GROUP BY from_id) AS internal
  FROM Referrals AS r JOIN Members AS m1 ON m1.id=r.from_id WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR  GROUP BY r.from_id)
```

Comment: This issue with using the above is when looping through the results it is putting each of the select statements as a new row in a while loop. I thought using Union all that it would return the results of all three selects per row.

Answer (score 0):

So i might possibly help others in this situation this is what gave me the results I was looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS total, CONCAT(m1.first_name,' ', m1.last_name) AS fromName, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Referrals WHERE rtype=1 AND from_id=r.from_id GROUP BY fromName) AS external,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Referrals WHERE rtype=2 AND from_id=r.from_id GROUP BY fromName) AS internal
FROM Referrals AS r JOIN Members AS m1 ON m1.id=r.from_id WHERE QUARTER(rdate) = @LASTQTR AND YEAR(rdate) = @YR  GROUP BY fromName ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```